# R - Add a new column to the data frame and duplicate the existing rows

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this,

```
ColA  ColB  
Asd   1
Asdf  3
```

I want to add a new column to the data frame, lets say the new column has values as 2000,2001,2002. These value needs to be added for each value in ColA.

So my expected dataframe is,

```
ColA   ColB   Year
Asd     1      2000
Asd     1      2001
Asd     1      2002
Asdf    3      2000
Asdf    3      2001
Asdf    3      2002
```

Comment: @akrun sorry that was an error that I made. Corrected it now. it has to be 3.

Comment: Try `library(data.table);setDT(df1)[, .(Year = 2000:2002), .(ColA, ColB)]`

Comment: `cbind(df, year = rep(2000:2002, nlevels(df$ColA)))` and then order it.

Comment: @RichScriven It worked. But why is it displaying the header rows at the end of the dataframe as well? But it doesn't really matter, as when I checked the dataframe, its not a part of the dataframe. so, its fine. Can you write that as an answer?

Comment: @akrun - It worked. Can one of you, write that as a solution. I will mark it up as an answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `data.table`, we can group by `ColA, ColB` and get the sequence of 'year' as a column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(Year = 2000:2002), .(ColA, ColB)]
```

---

Or in `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(df1, year = 2000:2002)
#  ColA ColB year
#1  Asd    1 2000
#2  Asd    1 2001
#3  Asd    1 2002
#4 Asdf    3 2000
#5 Asdf    3 2001
#6 Asdf    3 2002
```